# realy long time between invoking dispatcher and execution

Tags: c#, .net, dispatcher

I apologize beforehand if this is a stupid question. I am an embedded C programmer by profession and C# is relatively new to me.

I have an application which basically boils down to the following: One thread which polls an external interface (profibus in case anyone is interested), when the input data changes an event is raised and the new data is handled.
Since the data I need to update uses databinding I invoke the dispatcher. This setup works properly millions of times, but sometimes it takes up to 6 seconds before the code in the delegate is executed. Since there are no other threads, I can not see any reason for this.
I use the following event handler. Container is a reference to the TabItem to which the class is databound.

```
public void newSlave_InputChanged(object sender, InputChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime beforeDisp = DateTime.Now;
        Container.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (Action)delegate()
        {
            DateTime afterDisp = DateTime.Now;
            if (afterDisp.Subtract(beforeDisp).TotalSeconds > 1)
            {
                /* Breakpoint here to detect the problem */               
            }
            /* Do the work I need to do */           

        }
    );
    }
```

The thread polling the external interface basically look something like this:

```
void monitorSlaves()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (cardOnline)
            {
                foreach (slave slv in slaves)
                {
                    /* get the data */
                        if (dataChanged)
                        {
                            /* raise event */
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: Monitor slaves", DateTime.Now));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
```

I have added the print to see if this thread is still running while the dispatcher "hangs". As it turns out, it does not. I have no idea what the program is doing in the seconds in between the invocation and the execution, since there are no other threads running as far as I know. Unfortunately I do not have a visual studio 2010 ultimate license, so I cannot use intellitrace to backtrace what ran.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it help to use a performance profiler (like e.g. Red Gate ANTS Profiler) to finde where the 6 seconds go? Or would it take years to find the one in a million times when it occurs?

Comment: What is the spec of the machine running this? Is it a normal PC or a cut-down device?

Comment: Fortunately it doesn't take years. Sometimes the application runs for a full night without any problems, but most of the time it will happen within an hour after starting. I will look into profilers, but I am afraid that we do not have any licenses for this kind of software. I'll see if I can find some freeware alternative.

Comment: It is a normal PC. I normally do embedded, but this a tool to simulate something our embedded platform interacts with

Comment: ANTS Profiler is free for 30 days to try. Should be enough to find the issue and if it really helps, maybe there _is_ money for the next similar issue, if it saves you time.

Comment: Thank a lot. I will surely give it a try.

Comment: `Container.Dispatcher.Invoke` - doesn't that dispatch your delegate to the GUI thread? If this code is a method in a Form then I believe it does. The InputChanged event is also on the GUI thread. Perhaps the GUI thread is busy with other stuff (such as a large number of other Invokes sent from other places that take a while to process.

Answer (score 0):

using thread.sleep is generally bad practice, you might be freezing the entire UI thread so that the Dispatcher is not being called properly. I recommend using a DispatcherTimer instead

Comment: That code I assume is running on the background thread, right?

Comment: The thread sleep is in a different thread than the UI thread. This thread continually polls the external interface.

Comment: does the problem remain if you use a dispatchertimer and begininvoke instead of invoke?

Comment: I can't use a dispachtertimer because the polling thread is in a separate DLL which knows nothing of any GUI. It is bascially just a wrapper for the DLL of the interface card I used. I have tried beginInvoke, but unfortunately the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're seeing the input when you think you are?

One possible problem is that the interface card DLL is not reporting the input to you in a timely manner.

Another possible problem is that the UI thread is too busy to run your delegate. However, 6 seconds is a *long* time to be unresponsive.

You can add simple tracing to determine the cause. Just call `Trace.TraceInformation` to log simple strings in Release mode. Then download [`DebugView`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647), which can display those trace messages. You can also set up DebugView to timestamp them and save them to a file.

P.S. Coincidentally, I'm a .NET developer who is now working on embedded firmware. :)

Answer (score 0):

I bet the delay because of garbage collector is gathering bunch of small objects which you created. run perfmon and watch all the collection.